# Разделить строку по разделителям, а потом по известным словам

Tags: java, строки, парсер

Подскажите парсер для строк, написанный на Java.

Правила просты: если в строке есть стандартные для письма разделители, то разделить по ним, а также нужно разделить по словам, даже если разделителей никаких нет.

Например, строка: "Антивирусблокируетмоюjavaпрограмму".
Задать парсеру список возможных слов и разделителей, по которым тот, в свою очередь, разобъёт строку.
Понятно, что написать можно и самому, но, если есть готовая реализация, прошу подсказать.

Comment: Для того, чтобы разбить строку у класса String есть метод `spring(String regex)`, который принимает регулярное выражение.

Comment: Регулярные выражения очень гибкие, так что можно разбить строку по любым разделителям

Answer (score 0):

###### Обновлённый ответ

Для разбиения строки на слова, согласно вашим требованиям, могу предложить такое решение:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class CustomParser {

    public static String[] splitString(String input, String separatorsRegex, final Iterable<String> knownWords) {
        String wordsRegex = String.join("|", knownWords);
        String regex = separatorsRegex + "|(?<=(" + wordsRegex + "))|(?=(" + wordsRegex + "))";
        return input.split(regex);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String input = "Антивирусблокируетмоюjavaпрограмму пример;других.слов:разделённых!разделителями";

        // Регулярное выражение, задающее разделитель
        String separatorsRegex = "[\\s.,:;!?\\\\/]+";

        List<String> knownWords = List.of("Антивирус", "блокирует", "мою", "java", "программу");

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splitString(input, separatorsRegex, knownWords)));
    }
}
```

Объяснение:

1. Метод `splitString` принимает три параметра:

   - строку `input`, которую необходимо разбить;
   - строку `separatorsRegex`, представляющую из себя регулярное выражение, описывающее разделитель (если подстрока в строке `input` определяется этим выражением, то на месте этой подстроки происходит разделение);
   - итерируемый объект `knownWords`, хранящий "список" известных слов, которые будут разделены в случае, если они будут "слеплены вместе".
2. Описание работы метода `splitString`:
   Метод составляет регулярное выражение, которое можно описать следующим образом: "разделитель или сзади известное слово или спереди известное слово" - и применяет его к строке `input`. Результирующий массив возвращается.

---

###### Старый ответ

Этот ответ был изначальным и навёл меня на мысль о новом ответе, поэтому решил не удалять.

Для разбиения строки на слова, согласно вашим требованиям, могу предложить такое решение:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class CustomParser {

    public static List<String> splitString(String input, String separatorsRegex, final Iterable<String> knownWords) {

        // Шаг 1
        // Разделяем строку по разделителям
        String[] tokens = input.split(separatorsRegex);

        // Шаг 2
        // Составляем регулярное выражение
        String wordsRegex = String.join("|", knownWords);
        wordsRegex = "(?<=(" + wordsRegex + "))|(?=(" + wordsRegex + "))";
        // Компилируем регулярное выражение
        Pattern wordsPattern = Pattern.compile(wordsRegex);

        // Разделяем каждый токен на слова
        ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String token : tokens)
            words.addAll(List.of(wordsPattern.split(token)));
        return words;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String input = "Антивирусблокируетмоюjavaпрограмму пример;других.слов:разделённых!разделителями";

        // Регулярное выражение, задающее разделитель
        String separatorsRegex = "[\\s.,:;!?\\\\/]+";

        List<String> knownWords = List.of("Антивирус", "блокирует", "мою", "java", "программу");

        System.out.println(splitString(input, separatorsRegex, knownWords));
    }
}
```

Объяснение:

1. Метод `splitString` принимает три параметра:

   - строку `input`, которую необходимо разбить;
   - строку `separatorsRegex`, представляющую из себя регулярное выражение, описывающее разделитель (если подстрока в строке `input` определяется этим выражением, то на месте этой подстроки происходит разделение);
   - итерируемый объект `knownWords`, хранящий "список" известных слов, которые будут разделены в случае, если они будут "слеплены вместе".
2. Описание работы метода `splitString`:

   - Шаг 1: с помощью функции Strin::split происходит разбивка строки `input` на подстроки с помощью регулярного выражения `separatorsRegex`;
   - Шаг 2: создаётся регулярное выражение на основе итерируемого объекта `knownWords`. Его можно описать так: "сзади известное слово или спереди известное слово". Затем это регулярное выражение применяется ко всем токенам, которые были получены на первом шаге - и все полученные слова заносятся в новый список.